# how to install two versions of tomcat 6 and 7 with java 6 and 7 respectively on same ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, java

Can any one help me to configure a server with two tomcat instances i.e. tomcat 6 with java 6 and tomcat 7 with java 7 versions on a same ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to install diff-versioned software on the same server but (I think) the best variant is packing your application into different [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) containers.